# What is the crank on the ceiling of this aircraft?

Tags: flight-controls, cockpit, aircraft-identification, feature-identification

What is the crank the pilot is operating above his head? Also what type of aircraft is this?

[image]

<sup>[image source](https://youtu.be/wz0-08ny2G8)</sup>

Comment: Where did you get the image from? Is this a frame grab out of a video? Mind attributing the source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's out of Friendly Skies Film's YouTube channel, though exactly which video I don't know...

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/puOU48eFOlM?t=4m29s) is not the video from which this picture came, but it explains which way to turn the crank.

Comment: Aha, I was right! It was from his channel. [That scene starts here.](https://youtu.be/jBB6PIm-6tg?t=1m52s) The plane is N8831N.

Comment: Oops, added the citation. It's a screen grab from the linked YouTube video

Comment: It's an engineless helicopter. That's the crank that turns the main rotor. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pilot is operating the [overhead stabilator trim crank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0DtF_mYdO0) in an early model [Piper Cherokee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-28_Cherokee). Here's a close up the trim crank:

[image: Trim crank]

Piper Cherokee overhead trim crank; image from [tnwings.com](http://www.tnwings.com/images/DSC04027.JPG)

In later models, it was replaced with [airliner type trim wheels](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1thGE06bMDsC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=piper+cherokee+overhead+trim+crank&source=bl&ots=0AUQzybBFa&sig=nUzzDe8QXf055Ez4NRkV-8AOcw0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibudCymqDRAhUGKY8KHf8aDToQ6AEIVzAL#v=onepage&q=piper%20cherokee%20overhead%20trim%20crank&f=false)

Comment: I commented on the other answer but the Comanche's also had this, it isn't clear which of the piper PA-24, 28 just from the picture. It may even be a Twin Comanche

Comment: @RonBeyer In other places in the video I grabbed that from they show a PA-28-151, reg # N8027F. Most likely the same plane. Hadn't thought of checking the tail num when I posted the question :) Never seen a trim crank on the ceiling before. But, I've never been in a piper before either

Comment: @TomMcW As I previously mentioned to you, the plane in your screenshot is N8831N. (See [this video](https://youtu.be/4gmMTA4Z7H0?t=42s) for the explanation.)

Answer (score 3):

That's a pitch trim control.  The older PA-28-140 Warriors had their manual elevator (stabilator) trim as an overhead crank like that.  Later versions of the PA-28 moved the trim to a friction wheel between the front seats behind the flap lever.

Comment: The Comanche's have it too, I occasionally fly a PA-24-180 with the ceiling trim crank. A good way to remember how it works is you screw it in to go up, and unscrew it to go down.

Comment: @RonBeyer Better not screw it up!

Comment: My 1968 Cherokee has this design and when you first start to fly it you have to think about which way to crank. After a while you don’t think about it anymore and your hand just knows which way to crank.

Comment: @JScarry Yep, becomes totally automatic after just a few hours. The same issue presents on trim wheel type systems; you just learn it with time.